# pyarrow dataset to_table filter by index

Tags: python, indexing, dataset, pyarrow

I have a pyarrow dataset that I'm trying to filter by index.
The pyarrow documentation presents filters by column or "field" but it is not clear how to do this for index filtering.
I have inspected my table by printing the result of `dataset.to_table()` and found that the index column is labeled `__index_level_0__: string`.
Then I managed to filter the index by using that value as my field i.e:
`dataset.to_table(filter=ds.field("__index_level_0__") == 'index_to_search_for')`

Is there a better way of going about filtering by index?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a better way of going about filtering by index?

At the moment, there is not really a better approach.  There are some details that could help you.

First, you will want to make sure the index is actually materialized as a column.  When possible, Arrow will store a simple range index as metadata instead of an actual column.  For more details on this process you can read [here](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/pandas.html#handling-pandas-indexes).  To ensure the indices are stored as columns pass `preserve_index=True` when converting from Pandas to Arrow (you haven't described how you are doing this so I'm not sure what exact function you would pass this to).

Second, you will need to get the index column names.  Guessing that it will be `__index_level_0__` might work if you always have a single column index and it never has a name.  Alternatively, there are two ways deal with incoming data more flexibly.

You could assign names to the index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x': [1, 2, 3]})
df.index.name = 'idx'
pa.Table.from_pandas(df, preserve_index=True).field('idx')
# pyarrow.Field<idx: int64>
```

Or you can extract the index columns out of the metadata of the Arrow table:

```
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df, preserve_index=True)
pandas_meta_str = table.schema.metadata[b'pandas']
pandas_meta = json.loads(pandas_meta_str)
pandas_meta['index_columns']
# ['idx']
table.field(pandas_meta['index_columns'][0])
# pyarrow.Field<idx: int64>
```